# Is there an android app to switch between static IPs profiles?

Tags: android

I have several different IP networks on my home, each for another use, for example main internet use 192.168.1.0/24 (with dhcp server), lights on 192.168.2.0/24 etc.

on the other subnets there isn't a dhcp server, therefore you should connect with a static IP. there are some times that a simple login can be done from my mobile, but there is the added time and effort to setup each time the static IP.

On my laptop running windows, i use TCP/IP Manager to switch IPs between my home static various networks and my work static IP.

Do you know of an android app that can store some profiles and can switch between them easily?

Comment: For what Android version? For older apps there exists a function named `updateNetwork` do modify a Wifi profile (which might be usable to apply a static IP for a Wifi network) but this API is no longer functional for aps targeting Android 10 and above. I am not sure if modification of an existing Wifi profile is still possible with the successor of that function. Conclusion for older Android versions such an app might exist, for newer versions I don't know if it is possible at all.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your reply! I am now using android 10, do you know of any apps that could do this task?